# Cookie set in codebehind not set on server but works local

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, cookies

To check if a document is sent to the browser I'm creating a cookie and checking if it exists in javascript. I got it to work on localhost, but for some reason it doesn't work after I deployed it to the server.

Codebehind:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("download", "complete");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Javascript:

```
function waitForDownload() {
    if (getCookie("download") === "complete") { //getCookie method works
        //do something
    } else {
        setTimeout(waitForDownload, 500);
    }
}
```

I think the cookie doesn't get created, I can't find it when looking for it in the chrome console (Checking before the 10 seconds are over).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may need to add this to allow the cookie to be accessed by javascript. Try:

```
cookie.HttpOnly = false;
```

Comment: I guess it is false by default

Comment: Not in my recent experience

Comment: Yes, it is.  This isn't relevant, especially if it works in one environment but not another.

Comment: @SteveHarris Check the documentation then - your recent experience has taught you something that isn't correct... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.httponly(v=vs.110).aspx `The default is false.`

Comment: Strange how this exact change fixed a similar issue for me. Why not try and see if it makes a difference and if not, then that wasn't much time wasted.

Comment: @Archer Sorry to disappoint you, but this actually solved the problem. Thanks Steve!

Comment: Why would that disappoint me??  It was set to true somewhere else so this fixed it.

Comment: Need an emoji with shades